# How to store the form values from one html file to table of another html file?

Tags: javascript

How do I send the value of first html code to another html file (like table format) using JavaScript?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Registration Form</title> 
</head>
 
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<form action="empDataEntryDisplay.html" method="GET">
<table align="center" width="50%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="5">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><b>Employee Registration Form</b></td>   
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Employee Number<span style="color:red">*</span></td>
        <td width="57%"><input type="text" value="" id="emp_num" size="41"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Employee Name<span style="color:red">*</span></td>
        <td width="57%"><input type="text" value="" id="emp_name" size="41"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Employee Age</td>
        <td width="57%"><input type="text" value="" id="emp_age" size="41"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Date of Birth</td>
        <td width="57%"><input type="date" value="" id="emp_dob" style="width:98.5%"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Address</td>
        <td width="57%"><textarea rows="4" maxlen="200" id="emp_address" cols="38"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Contact Number</td>
        <td width="57%"><input type="text" value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="emp_con_num" size="41"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr >
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Job Location</td>
        <td width="57%">
            <select name="mydropdown" id="emp_job_place" style="width:100%">
                <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
                <option value="Arrupukottai">Arrupukottai</option>
                <option value="Kurunthancode">Kurunthancode</option>
                <option value="Thirunelveli">Thirunelveli</option>
                <option value="Valliore">Valliore</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
 
    <tr >
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Designation</td>
        <td width="57%">
            <select name="mydropdown" id="emp_designaion" style="width:100%">
                <option value="Trainee">Trainee</option>
                <option value="Proof Reader">Proof Reader</option>
                <option value="Senior Proof Reader">Senior Proof Reader</option>
                <option value="Layout Expert">Layout Expert</option>
                <option value="Senior Layout Expert">Senior Layout Expert</option>
                <option value="Template Developer">Template Developer</option>
                <option value="Senior Template Developer">Senior Template Developer</option>
                <option value="Designer">Designer</option>
                <option value="Senior Designer">Senior Designer</option>
                <option value="Image Developer">Image Developer</option>
                <option value="SeniorImage Developer">Senior Image Developer</option>
                <option value="Team Leader">Team Leader</option>
                <option value="Assistant Team Leader">Assistant Team Leader</option>
                <option value="Production Manager">Production Manager</option>
                <option value="Assistant Production Manager">Assistant Production Manager</option>
                <option value="Senior Production Manager">Senior Production Manager</option>
                <option value="Project Manager">Project Manager</option>
                <option value="Project Manager">Assistant Project Manager</option>
                <option value="Project Manager">Senior Project Manager</option>
                <option value="Project Manager">Copy Editor</option>
                <option value="System Administrator">System Administrator</option>
                <option value="Senior System Administrator">Senior System Administrator</option>
                <option value="Operations Head">Operations Head</option>
                <option value="Vice President">Vice President</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="41%">Email<span style="color:red">*</span></td>
        <td width="57%"><input type="text" value="" id="emp_email" size="41"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()"></td>
    </tr> 

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my another html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Registration Data Storage</title> 
</head>
 
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID Number</b></td>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Age</b></td>
        <td><b>Date of Birth</b></td>
        <td><b>Address</b></td>
        <td><b>Contact Number</b></td>
        <td><b>Job Location</b></td>
        <td><b>Designation</b></td>
        <td><b>e-Mail</b></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend you do some research, find some tutorials. If you still have problems once you have made an attempt to achieve your goal then return and seek help explaining your attempt / goal and problem.

Comment: There are multiple solutions, depending on what techs you are using. Back end or only frontend? You could use SessionStorage on frontend, and back-end you could save the data to the server and display on the 2º page (html)

Comment: Google js localStorage ...